# unable to see drupal home page when configured live site into in my local system?

Tags: theming

> I need to configured my live site into local system, I had configured database, settings.php and enable module rewrite and .htaccess file also there in my root folder etc.
>
> But I'm unable to see the my site home page it's showing blank page, please help me I'm new to drupal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
```

in index.php file, that will be showing the actual error on front page.

Comment: hi my actual code  in index.php is define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
now i changed like 


<?php
        define("DRUPAL_ROOT", "/var/www/html/mydrupal/");
        require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
        drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
?>
but geeting same error @ Himanshu Pathak

Comment: <?php define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();              this should be code on index.php

Comment: okay.thank you it's working but css missing i have given path also where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Provide 777 permission to files folder. from drupal root folder, run this command "sudo chmod 777 -R sites/default/files"

Comment: okay,permission's already there issue in base url at settings.php i have changed it's working good now

Comment: congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your local apache might need configuration.

The best way to avoid these type of errors is to set up a virtual host for your local site so that your URL is like this: http://sitename.dev (That's what I do for all my local sites).

I can see in your screenshot you have http://192.168.1.98/sitename so maybe apache is pointing to the wrong place.

Also check your apache error log to see what error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you ,i will set up  virtual host for my local site@Rick Bergmann